# How to enable a campain in Adwords with automated rules based on another campaign status

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to create a automated rule to enable a campaign when another gets paused. But I'm a bit confused about how to do it.

Specifically, what I want to do is:

When campaign A cost is X ==> Pause *campaign A*

When campaign A is paused ==> Enable *campaign B*

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it's not possible to do a rule based on an other campaign so I had to to it by using the api through the [CampaignService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201306/CampaignService)